# cant get the number of seconds in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code to get the current date and hour:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kabul');
$today = date('Ymdh');
echo $today; // prints 2015020212 Fine
```

I was wondering if I could get it's number of seconds! But the following does not give me that.

```
echo strtotime($today);
```

I really need to get date `2015020212` in seconds! please help me!

Comment: What do you mean "get in seconds"? `date('U')` returns the current unix timestamp in seconds since the unix epoch, as does `time()`

Comment: It is unclear whether you want the date represented as seconds (in which case, time() will give you the number of seconds since 01-01-1970. Or whether you want the seconds of the current time, in which case you want date('s');

Comment: how about using **echo strtotime("now");** ?

Comment: @CodingHorror, there is no need for `strtotime('now')`, if anything, then use `time()`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `strtotime` is not returning what you expect is because you need to give it the date in the correct format:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
strtotime($today);
```

and

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
strtotime($today);
```

will work, but you have given it `Ymdh`, which PHP has no idea how to interpret.

For more info on valid formats check out [the page in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date('Ymdh h:i:s')` if you're looking for the local time as well.

`h` would give the 12 hour format of the hour with leading zeroes;
`i` for minutes; and
`s` for seconds.

Source : [PHP Date Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: He says he needs the date in seconds, not that he wants to add the minutes and seconds onto the date. Unless you just really good at interpretting ambiguious questions!

Comment: You are giving a hint here, not the proper answer :)

Comment: Hmm yes. I might have misunderstood the question. Let's wait for the OP to respond.

Comment: if you fix/wide your answer to the actual question this would be a perfectly legitimate answer, imho :)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need something like this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$time_in_seconds = $date->getTimestamp();
```